# Field Calculator - conditional function and string variable?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator, python-parser, conditional

I know this question has been asked before in different fashions, but I can't seem to get my python script to work despite looking at all the relevant questions I could find.

I am simply trying to populate an attribute field based on the conditions of another attribute field.  Specifically I have one field that labels various projects under different headings (example: easement, BPS, donated etc.)

I want to calculate the values in a new field to group these into one of three headings (Donated Easement, Purchased Easement, BPS).  However I can't get the python to work and I would rather not do it by hand.  Here is the code I ran just to try to get one label type recalculated.

pre-logic:

```
def reLabel(typeLabel):
  if typeLabel == 'BPS Easement':
    return 'BPS'
  else:
    return 'Other'
```

Label2:

```
reLabel(!Type_Label!)
```

[image: Table]

Comment: this looks OK (except indentation,but I guess this is correct in your code). note that the comparison is case sensitive. by the way, have you tried to select and update your field, this wold be a quick workaround with only 3 categories and you would directly see if the selection is not doing what you expect

Comment: Yes, the indentation is not where I am getting the error.  I keep getting an error that says "Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid."  and another "Error 000735: Input Table: Value is required"

Comment: have you tried my workaround ? with your present description of the issue there is little we can do to help. Maybe you could add a snapshot of your table.

Comment: Yes, the workaround would work, but I would like to sort out how to do this through Python if possible.  I added a screenshot  above.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is off, you're missing an indent on the "Else" line:

```
def reLabel(typeLabel):
  if typeLabel == 'BPS Easement':
    return 'BPS'
  else:
    return 'Other'
```

Comment: The indentation is not where I am getting the error.  I keep getting an error that says "Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid."  and another "Error 000735: Input Table: Value is required"

Answer (score 0):

I ended up selecting all the features in the layer and exporting to a new layer.  The python script worked fine after that.  Not sure what the issue was but this resolved it.